# Keeping socket open for UDP?

Tags: sockets, network-programming

Using TCP, the workflow for sending the data is following:

```
- open socket()
- write(data1)
- write(data2)
- write ... data n
- close(socket)
```

But how is it with UDP? Do we keep the socket open? Or do we open the socket every time the data is ready? What is the best practice for that?

```
- open socket();
- write(data1);
- close(socket);


- open socket();
- write(data2);
- close(socket);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening a TCP socket usually means

- create a socket structure in operating system
- establish a TCP connection (3 way handshake with a peer)

and closing a TCP socket means

- TCP connection release
- delete socket structure in operating system

Opening a UDP socket does not trigger any network communication and it only creates a socket structure in OS.

Opening a TCP socket is more costly that opening a UDP socket because opening and closing a TCP socket creates a TCP session whereas opening and closing a UDP socket is a local action only.

It is best practice to reuse existing UDP socket for sending/receiving more than one datagram. It is useless to close a UDP socket if it can be reused for later communication. Moreover if the application closed the UDP socket then incoming  traffic to port, that was bound to the socket, would be lost.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it makes sense keep the socket open if you have more to send (or receive).